# Program is not responding in Code::blocks after reading my input

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am trying to make a program within code::blocks that will allow me to select multiple unit conversions to do. However, whenever I build and compile and reach the point in the program where it scans in my input for the variable "choice", code::blocks displays a window immediately afterwards that says that my .exe has stopped working and I can't figure out why this is the case. I am using the GNU GCC Compiler. Any help would be enormously appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float fahrenheit;
    float celsius;
    float pound;
    float kilogram;
    float inch;
    float centimeter;
    float mph;
    float kph;
    int foc;
    int pok;
    int ioc;
    int mok;
    int choice;

    printf("\n1. Temperature Conversion\n");
    printf("\n2. Weight Conversion\n");
    printf("\n3. Length Conversion\n");
    printf("\n4. Speed Conversion\n");
    printf("\n5. Exit Program\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nEnter the number of the program you would like to run :\n");
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", choice);

    //Temperature Conversion
    if(choice == 1) {
        printf("\n1. Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit\n");
        printf("\n2. Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius\n");
        printf("\nEnter the number that corresponds with the conversion you would like to do:\n");
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%d", &foc);

        if(foc == 1) {
            //option 1
            printf("\nEnter your temperature in Celsius : ");
            scanf("%f", &celsius);
            fahrenheit = 32 + (celsius * 1.8);
            printf("\nYour temperature in Fahrenheit : %f ", fahrenheit);
        }
        else {
            //option 2
            printf("\nEnter your temperature in Fahrenheit : ");
            scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);
            celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 0.55555555;
            printf("\nYour temperature in Celsius : %f ", celsius);
        }
    }
    //Weight Conversion
    else if(choice == 2) {
        printf("\n1. Convert from Pound to Kilogram ");
        printf("\n2. Convert from Kilogram to Pound ");
        printf("\nEnter the number that corresponds with the conversion you would like to do: ");
        printf("\n ");
        scanf("%d", &pok);

        if(pok == 1) {
            //option 1
            printf("\nEnter your weight in pounds : ");
            scanf("%f", &pound);
            kilogram = (2.20462 * pound);
            printf("\nYour weight in kilograms : %f ", kilogram);
        }
        else {
            //option 2
            printf("\nEnter your weight in kilograms : ");
            scanf("%f", &kilogram);
            pound = (kilogram/2.20462);
            printf("\nYour weight in pounds : %f ", celsius);
        }
    }
    //Length Conversion
    else if(choice == 3) {
        printf("\n1. Convert from inches to centimeters ");
        printf("\n2. Convert from centimeters to inches ");
        printf("\nEnter the number that corresponds with the conversion you would like to do: ");
        printf("\n ");
        scanf("%d", &ioc);

        if(ioc == 1) {
            //option 1
            printf("\nEnter your length in inches : ");
            scanf("%f", &inch);
            centimeter = (inch/2.54);
            printf("\nYour length in centimeters : %f ", centimeter);
        }
        else {
            //option 2
            printf("\nEnter your length in centimeters : ");
            scanf("%f", &centimeter);
            inch = (centimeter*2.54);
            printf("\nYour length in inches : %f ", inch);
        }
    }
    //Speed Conversion
    else if(choice == 4) {
        printf("\n1. Convert from mph to kph ");
        printf("\n2. Convert from kph to mph ");
        printf("\nEnter the number that corresponds with the conversion you would like to do: ");
        printf("\n ");
        scanf("%d", &mok);

        if(mok == 1) {
            //option 1
            printf("\nEnter your speed in mph : ");
            scanf("%f", &mph);
            kph = (mph/1.60934);
            printf("\nYour speed in kilometers: %f ", kph);
        }
        else {
            //option 2
            printf("\nEnter your speed in kph : ");
            scanf("%f", &kph);
            mph = (1.60934*kph);
            printf("\nYour length in inches : %f ", mph);
        }
    }
    else if(choice == 5) {
        printf("\nProgram has ended. Thanks for your time!");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nThat is not a valid program number. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well u already got the answer but i suggest u to use switch-case statements to make your code more readable instead of if else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the *pointer* to the `choice` variable (i.e. `&choice`) to your `scanf()` call, just as you've done for your other `scanf()` uses.

I.e. instead of

```
scanf("%d", choice);
```

use

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

Comment: I'm still a quite the noob at C-Programming so would it be possible for you to expand on this?

Comment: @CerebralCortexan  You missed `&` in that expression . `%d` requires address of `int` as argument and you are passing an `int` . Therefore, you need _address of variable `choice`_ .

Comment: @CerebralCortexan, what would you like to know? Do you know why you have to pass a pointer? Do you know what a pointer is?

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum, use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  then fix those warnings.  For the posted code, there are two warnings raised.  1) line 27, warning: format '%d' expects  argument of type 'int*' but argument 2 has type 'int'   2) line 27, warning: 'choice' is used uninitialized in this function.    These are both for the source statement: `scanf("%d", choice);`  which should be: `scanf( "%d", &choice);` and the code should check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Suggest writing a sub function for each valid 'choice' value, use a switch statement with a case for each valid 'choice' value, etc.   This would greatly simplify the code, make it much more understandable, and localize/separate the functionality for each 'choice' value.

Answer (score 0):

scanf() reads a value from the user and the address of the variable must be represented in the syntax
if not represented the program takes the garbage value so